# Understanding SQL Query Beginner

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL and would like some help in understanding the below query.  I'm basically looking to understand what the query is actually doing.  If someone could take me through what this is doing I think that may help me out a bunch.  Thank you

```
SELECT V.NAME AS Vendor_name
    ,PO.ID AS PURC_ORDER_ID
    ,POL.LINE_NO
    ,POL.VENDOR_PART_ID
    ,PO.STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,STATUS
        ,VENDOR_ID
    FROM PURCHASE_ORDER
    ) PO
INNER JOIN Purc_order_line POL ON PO.ID = POL.PURC_ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,NAME
    FROM vendor
    ) V ON PO.VENDOR_ID = V.ID
WHERE PO.ID = '16471'
```

Comment: What don't you understand? It selects some columns from some tables which are linked via foreignkey -> primarykey and filters by an `ID`.

Comment: If you're just beginning to learn SQL, it might make sense to start with some more basic sample queries.

Comment: To be fair, those sub queries are a bit spammy and make it look more messy than it needs to.

Comment: basically, its selecting a few columns with aliased names (via AS) from an imaginary table its creating in memory via the sub select query inner joining on some foreign key relationships and then filtering it by the final where clause

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'm just a little frustrated and don't have any formal SQL training but more that willing to learn, which I'm excited to do.  I do understand the basics but the sub selects make my head spin for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select V.Name as Vendor_name, PO.ID as PURC_ORDER_ID, POL.LINE_NO, POL.VENDOR_PART_ID, PO.STATUS
from   (select ID, STATUS, VENDOR_ID from PURCHASE_ORDER) PO 
           inner join Purc_order_line POL
             on PO.ID = POL.PURC_ORDER_ID
           inner join (select ID, name from vendor) V
             on PO.VENDOR_ID = V.ID
where PO.ID = '16471'
```

It's doing a few things which are strange to me but lets walk though it:  The strangeness has to do with the subqueries/inline views, they aren't needed and add to the complexity of the read.  it could be written as:

```
select V.Name as Vendor_name, PO.ID as PURC_ORDER_ID, POL.LINE_NO, POL.VENDOR_PART_ID, PO.STATUS
from   PURCHASE_ORDER PO 
inner join Purc_order_line POL
  on PO.ID = POL.PURC_ORDER_ID
inner join vendor V
  on PO.VENDOR_ID = V.ID
where PO.ID = '16471'
```

and you would get the same results.

SQL is read inside out.  So look first at the inner most from clause.

1. It's generating an inline view on vendor and calling it (alias) 'V' containing ID, and Name.
2. It's generating an inline view on Purchase_Order and using an alias 'PO' containing fields ID, status, vendor_Id
3. It's joining Purchase_order_line, Vendor, and Purchase_order together using inner joins.  This will result in a result set that contains all purchase orders, the lines on the orders, and the vendor name from which the order was placed.
4. Then it limits the results to only a specific Purchase order using the line `WHERE PO.ID = '16471'`
5. Lastly it returns as columns in the result set: vendor name, PO.ID, Line Numbers, vendor_part_IDs and status of the PO.  The query alias some of the column names to make them easier to understand.
   PO.ID is being relabeled as Purch_order_Id and V.Name is being called Vendor_Name.  This is often done to prevent confusion on what the data is for future readers.

So think of it this way.

If an order has 3 lines each order has 1 vendor then this would return 1*1*3 records.  1 for the vendor * 1 for the Purchase order * 3 for the lines.

If you change the where clause to a Different PO Id, you may have different number of rows. again because each PO has a specific vendor.  And Each PO may have many parts on it.  So in this case the number of rows returned should match the number of lines on a PO.

Comment: Thank you for you time and detail in this, it really does help me get a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the same but is more readable because it avoids sub-queries:

```
SELECT V.NAME AS Vendor_name, 
       PO.id  AS PURC_ORDER_ID, 
       POL.line_no, 
       POL.vendor_part_id, 
       PO.status 
FROM   purchase_order PO
INNER JOIN purc_order_line POL 
    ON PO.id = POL.purc_order_id 
INNER JOIN Vendor V
    ON PO.vendor_id = V.id 
WHERE PO.id = 16471
```

It select columns from different tables linked via foreign-keys(f.e. `PO.Vendor_id`) -> primary-keys(f.e. `V.ID`) using `INNER JOIN`. That links only to existing  records, so vendors which are not purchased are not included. The `WHERE` filters the resultset by a specific ID.

Comment: Thanks for the break down, I really appreciate you time.  This helps too.